# Understanding a proof regarding T-annihilators

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

This may be a silly question but I don´t undersand one part of the next proof:

Let $T:V\to V$ be a cyclic linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space with minimal polynomial $p^k(x)$ ($p$ is irreducible) and $k\in \mathbb Z^+$.

If $\vec v\in V$ has $p^m(x)$ as it´s T-annihilator with $m<k$ then $\exists \vec w\in V$ such that $\vec v = p(T)(\vec w)$

Proof: $T$ is a cyclic linear operator that is $\exists \vec a\in V$ such that $V=Z(a;T)$; hence there exists a polynomial $q(x)$ such that $\vec v =q(T)(\vec a)$. If $p$ and $q$ were relatively co-prime then the T-annihilator of $\vec v$ would be equal to the T-annihilator of $\vec a$, but that can´t happen since the T-annihilator of $\vec a$ is  the minimal polynomial of $T$ (this is because $T$ is a cyclic operator).

Hence $p$ and $q$ are not relatively co-prime; as $p$ is irreducible, the only non trivial divisor of $p$ is itself; hence $p$ divides $q$ that is there exists a polynomial $r(x)$ such that $q=pr$. Then we have that: $$q(T)(\vec a)= p(T)(r(T(\vec a))$$ but $q(T)(\vec a)=\vec v$ and if we let $\vec w=r(T)(\vec a)$ we have that :$$\vec v=p(T)(\vec w)$$

But I don´t understand the part that says that if $p$ and $q$ are relatively co-prime we have that the T-annihilator of $\vec a$ equals the T-annihilator of $\vec v$. Can someone please explain it to me?. I would really appreciate it :)